# Determine whether or not the series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty (\frac{n+4}{n+8})^n$ converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does the series converge or diverge?

The series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty (\frac{n+4}{n+8})^n$

I tried the root test to get rid of the nth power but the limit equaled $1$ so the test is inconclusive. How else can I determine if this series converges or diverges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write

$$a_n=\left(\frac{n+4}{n+8}\right)^n=\frac{\left(1+\frac{4}{n}\right)^n}{\left(1+\frac{8}{n}\right)^n}\to \frac{e^4}{e^8}=e^{-4}\ne 0\implies \,\,\text{the series diverges}$$

Comment: This is much prettier than my answer. Nice one. +1

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Wow, thank you!  I'm 6 days out of surgery and recovering at home.  That just made my day.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the expression for a term in this series using long division:

$$\frac{n+4}{n+8}=1-\frac{4}{n+8}$$

We recognize the limit:

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1-\frac{4}{n+8}\right)^n &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\left(1-\frac{4}{n+8}\right)^{n+8}\right)^{\frac{n}{n+8}}\\
&=\left(e^{-4}\right)^1\\
&\neq 0
\end{align}$$

Therefore, by the divergence test, this series diverges.

---

Alternatively, you could just use L'Hopital's rule directly to calculate the same limit:

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+4}{n+8}\right)^n &= \exp\ln\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+4}{n+8}\right)^n\\
&=\exp\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln\left(\frac{n+4}{n+8}\right)\\
&=\exp\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n+4)-\ln(n+8)}{n^{-1}}\\
&=\exp\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n+4}-\frac{1}{n+8}}{-n^{-2}}\\
&=\exp\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^2}{n+8}-\frac{n^2}{n+4}\right)\\
&=\exp\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-4n^2}{n^2+12n+32}\\
&=\exp(-4)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Are you allowed to ignore the $\frac{n}{n+8}$ because it tends to 1?

Comment: Yeah, more or less. I'm not ignoring it, so much as using the rule that $\lim f(x)^{g(x)}=(\lim f(x))^{\lim g(x)}$, in cases where both limits are defined, and where we don't get an indeterminate form.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
a_n
&=\left(\dfrac{n+u}{n+v}\right)^n\\
&=\left(\dfrac{n+v-v+u}{n+v}\right)^n\\
&=\left(1+\dfrac{-v+u}{n+v}\right)^n\\
&\to e^{u-v}\\
\end{array}
$

since
$(1+\frac{a}{x})^x
\to e^a
$.